# CURL Error 401 - Does PHP version cause this problem?

Tags: php, soap, curl

I have the following code:

```
$body = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>".$data."</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
$ch = curl_init($FD_Add);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "WS******._.1:********");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, DIR_ROOT."ABCDEFG/Certs/WS******._.1.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, DIR_ROOT."ABCDEFG/Certs/WS******._.1.key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, "ckp_***********");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($test_env){echo 'The result of your request is:<RESULT>'.$result.'</RESULT>br/>' ;}
curl_close($ch);
```

The response is an error 401 HTTP requires authentication. I have verified the user ID and Password to be correct. What I am wondering first is if the version of PHP could cause this error if it does not support CULROPT_AUTH as I am running PHP~v. 3.4 which from what I read does not support this option.

Anybody know if this could be the trouble?

Comment: I think if I was capable of building a time machine I wouldnt be asking this question. The PHP has just never been updated.

Comment: Can you double-check that PHP version number? I don't think that PHP3 ever got beyond v3.0.18 and that was nearly over 10 years ago! Oh, and if it is the case that you're using PHP 4.3 please upgrade, 4.3.0 is 9 years old!

Comment: If you're on PHP 3.x, your installation is horrifically insecure.

Comment: Not entirely sure about the version I just know its 3.x. I have asked that it be upgraded but get poor excuses to not upgrade. So yea definitely not a fan of working with ancient PHP but for now its a necessity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably fake it by issuing the basic auth header yourself:

```
$auth_header = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_HEADER, $auth_header);
```

but that's only available since Curl 7.10.3 and later. Your stone-age PHP is most likely using an equally stone-age CURL.

Really... PHP 3.4 is the equivalent of driving around in a car bought from the Flintstones. You should upgrade to something more modern, like a Model-T... those horseless carriages are pretty impressive.

Comment: THANK you.  Glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: Well atleast you answered the question. Also the server is not mine, I dont have access to it to upgrade, I am just putting together a site for somebody else and have never worked with such an old version of PHP myself.